# Compare two files, print header field if

Tags: file, header, awk, compare

I have two files:

File 1 (first line is a header)

```
gene h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 h7 h8...
gene_name1 e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 e7 e8...
gene_name2 ...
gene_name3 ...
...
```

File 2 (no header)

```
gene_name1 mean1 mean2 sd1 sd2
gene_name2 ...
gene_name3 ...
```

I would like to output header field if any of fields e1,e2,e3...in File1 is > mean1+3(sd1) from File2 for the corresponding gene_name. Example: if e1>mean1+3(sd1) TRUE, then print :

gene_name1 h1

If e2 >mean1+3(sd1) TRUE, then add h2 to the line:

gene_name1 h1 h2

Do that for each line if $1 matches both files. If there is no field in File1 that accomplishes the condition, leave it with a blank.

Desired output:

```
gene_name1 h1 h2
gene_name2 
gene_name3 h5 h6 h8
gene_name4 h1 h5
gene_name5 h3
gene_name6 
gene_name7 h2 h5 h7 h8
...
```

I was thinking in something like:

`awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2+3*$4;next} $1 in a` ... and then a 'for loop' for each field in File 1. But I do not know how to store header fields.

Comment: Your description isn't 100% clear to me, I have added an answer for what I believe you mean. If this is wrong please update the question with the expected output from my given input. It is always helpful to post a representative input and the expected output with types of questions.

Comment: Sorry for not being so clear, I updated the question

Comment: See edit, should now do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
FNR==NR {
    a[$1]=$2+3*$4
    next
}
FNR==1 {
    split($0,h,/ /)
    next
}
($1 in a){

    printf "%s ",$1

    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i > a[$1]) {
            printf "%s ",h[i] 
        }
    }
    print ""
}
```

Demo:

```
$ cat file1 
gene h1 h2 h3 
gene1 1.0 2.0 3.0
gene2 0.5 0.5 0.5
gene3 100 50 10

$ cat file2
gene1 1.0 2.0 0.10 0.20
gene2 2.4 2.6 0.24 0.45
gene3 1.4 5.3 1.33 0.32

$ awk -f script.awk file2 file1
gene1 h2 h3 
gene2 
gene3 h1 h2 h3
```